# Device reboots into recovery after flashing CyanogenMod

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing

I'm retrying to install CyanogenMod in my cellphone after some time. I did the following:

> [image]

I used the sideload method. Everything worked fine and I did precisely what is written in there. The problem now is that when I click on reboot system now, it reboots, turns the purple light on, vibrates and then get back to the recovery menu. The difference is that it returns to a different menu: The first menu was this:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

Now it's showing the same menu with this background: That is, the same menu with the laid down Android mascot. I don't know what is happening.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: When you are in the Cyanogenmod Recovery, can't you just install the zip files? (Apply update > choose from ...) And then reboot your phone and you should have Cyanogenmod installed.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab The problem is that I already did that. I installed via adb and applying the update from the menu. They both get me in the same place. What is weird is that the installation is actually being made with no errors.

Comment: The pull your battery, and boot your phone. It should work.

Comment: Or just select reboot system now from the Android System Recovery.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab It gives me the same thing. It gives me the Sony logo screen, then it vibrates and shows the purple light. Then it shows the Sony logo again and then vibrates and shows the purple light. Then it enters in the same menu. I've also tried to make it reboot via the menu, it gets back to the same.

Comment: That's strange, what's your device model?

Comment: @SuperThomasLab C2104 / Xperia L.

Comment: Could you try these steps: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2426426 They might help you.

Comment: Also try wiping /system and reflash the ROM.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab Okay. I'll try it now and will report the results later.

Answer (score 1):

How did you get to the cyanogen recovery?
Did you flash it from fastboot?

Was the device bootloader unlocked?
(or) Did you go through some `oem-unlock` fastboot command?

I suppose it is related to oem-unlocking. If the manufacturer chooses not to boot unsigned images on a locked bootloader, then this is the case. Many recent devices fall into this. In such case, you need to do oem-unlocking following the instructions from your device manufacturer and then install any custom roms.

Comment: Half of the answer is seeking clarification. Please seek clarification using comments on the question. You're privileged to comment anywhere.